# VBA - Increment variable value not changing

Tags: vba, variables, macros, increment

I'am writting a small macro for opening links in browsers tab. Every 10th link is opened in new window. Can you tell me why variable **index** is not changing its value?

```
Sub OpenHyperLinks()

Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim MaxTabs As Integer
MaxTabs = 10
Static index As Integer
index = 0

On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
    If index Mod MaxTabs = 0 Then
        xHyperlink.Follow NewWindow:=True
    Else
        xHyperlink.Follow NewWindow:=False
    End If
    Inc (index)
Next
End Sub
```

And incrementation function:

```
Function Inc(ByRef i As Integer)
   i = i + 1
End Function
```

**Thanks fo help :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no immediate reason for the index value not being incremented. The "On Error Resume Next' may be masking an error condition that is preventing the increment code from being called. I'd temporarily remove or comment out the error handler to diagnose that possibility further.

There's no reason to move the code that increments 'index' into a separate function. Replace `inc(Index)` with `index=index+1` and eliminate the increment function. Additionally, the `Inc` function really operates as a `Sub`, not a function, because it does not return a value to the caller.

Comment: +1 Agree best way is to increment within the subroutine itself rather than have separate function. Other option is to declare a public variable e.g. `Public index as Integer` and then get separate `sub` to increment it

Comment: Its is working :) Thank you! Now is next question: why new browser window is not openning?

Comment: this is not the answer to _"Can you tell me why variable index is not changing its value?"_ . Rather it's a workaround not to face the argument. For the real answer see my post

Comment: The specific reason the ByRef argument is being ignored is because the parenthesis force an evaluation that causes the argument to be passed by value regardless of the explicit declaration of the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

you must remove parenthesis

```
Inc index
```

the reason is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251432.aspx): since *"you're not interested in the return value of a function, you can call a function the same way you call a Sub procedure. Omit the parentheses, list the arguments, and do not assign the function to a variable"*

Comment: The reason is not specifically because of the disinterest in the return value of the function. The reason is because the parenthesis force a ByVal push of the argument to the function, regardless of the parameter's ByRef declaration.